# Twilio not working in asp mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, twilio

I am trying to implement two factor authentication in my project. For **SMS** service i use `twilio`. But when the `SendSmsMessage()` is called always it says:

> core.cs not found error

I have made a lot of search on the internet. But I could not find a solution. Any suggestions.

Comment: Are you running a project with the Twilio source project referenced or did you use NuGet to install Twilio?

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I think you're trying to copy the source directly into your code and hence having issues with the dependencies. My suggestion would be to install the Nuget package from [Package Manager Console](http://docs.nuget.org/consume/package-manager-console).

Then just run:

```
Install-Package Twilio
```

After installing it you should be able to get it going in any file by just doing the following:

```
using System;
using Twilio;
class Example 
{
  static void Main(string[] args) 
  {
    // Find your Account Sid and Auth Token at twilio.com/user/account
    string AccountSid = "{{ account_sid }}";
    string AuthToken = "{{ auth_token }}";
    var twilio = new TwilioRestClient(AccountSid, AuthToken);


    var sms = twilio.SendSmsMessage(from, to, message);

    Console.WriteLine(sms.Sid);
  }
}
```

Also, because you mentioned you're trying to do 2FA, it may be worth mentioning another one of our products called [Authy](https://www.authy.com/). Authy takes away al the complexity in two factor authentication and is obviously powered by Twilio. Here's a [link to a tutorial](https://www.twilio.com/docs/howto/walkthrough/two-factor-authentication/csharp/mvc) showing how to implement it in .NET MVC.

Let me know if I can help you further.